# How to identify list of cookbooks that are successfully executed, once chef-client ran in local mode?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-zero

I executed some cookbooks in chef-client using local mode option. After the run is completed, is there anyway, I can find, what cookbooks are successfully executed?

Answer (score 0):

How "after"? If you mean immediately after, you can use a [handler](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#event-handlers). If you mean much later, not really. Some data would get written to the `nodes/` folder, but it might not be what you mean and is overwritten each time you run.